# C# fetch GIT build number

Tags: c#, git

I am trying to get the git version number, tried with the following code

```
string gitVersion = String.Empty;
using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
        .GetManifestResourceStream("TryGitDescribe." + "version.txt"))
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    gitVersion = reader.ReadToEnd();
}

Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", gitVersion);
Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to continue");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Build event command : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" describe --long > "$(ProjectDir)\version.txt"

**>Error    1   The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" describe --long > "E:\Test-GIT-Version\Test-GIT-Version\version.txt"" exited with code 128.  Test-GIT-Version**

but had no luck. please help how to get GIT version number.

Comment: If you want to get `git` version from commandline executable you can run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" --version`

Comment: To use output redirection you need to use the `CMD.exe` file, or use the redirection handling of `ProcessStartInfo`, the syntax `> xxx` is an artifact of how command processors do things, not built into the normal "start a process" system.

Comment: @shytikov I want to get build number

Comment: Regardless of whether you want to find the changeset of the working folder or the version of git you have installed you still have to do output redirection correctly. Please take a look at [ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d624d8b2(v=vs.110).aspx) property.